# Help please to identify my Tandem

Tags: repair, frames, tandems

I have just purchased an old tandem, but don't know the make or year.
Can anyone help me to identify it.
The frame is steel and it has a frame number of 452599.
There are no decals fitted but I attach a photo of the front tube casting where a decal was probably fitted to indicate the make.
The wheels/rims are 26" x 1.3/8" and the rear has a Dunlop Motorette tyre fitted (still holding air).
The front handlebar has "Il Primo Milano" on it.
The hubs/brakes are Sturmey Archer (Front has a number 10 5 6 on it)[image: Tandem Picture 1]
There are four sprockets on the back hub.
The derailleur is a Benelux Super 60
The seats are marked Iscaselle.
From what I have been able to look up on the derailleur, it suggests it could be 1950's or 1960's but that is all I have found.
Many Thanks![Frame Number
![Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDrYA.jpg)

![Derailleur![Tandem 2
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baL4C.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baL4C.jpg)

Comment: Check carefully on the head tube, the bottom bracket, et al for a serial number.  Sometimes the serial number scheme gives a slight clue (though I don't know where you'd find a reference for that).  Also, there are other sites on the web that are more into antique bikes than this site.

Comment: There's a good chance it's a Claud Butler.  (Check out http://www.retrobike.co.uk/)

Comment: That's a gorgeous old-school tandem.  What did you do with it in the end?  Feel free to post an answer to your own question, and accept it by clicking the tick/checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a Claud Butler or a BSA, as the headbadge is the wrong shape.

The name on the handlebars and use of Benelux and Iscaselle suggests Italy (and Sturmey was big in hub brakes everywhere, so may not be British-made).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure after looking at hundreds of headtube badges on Google images, that that is a Royal Enfield.  I just bought a tandem that looks VERY similar but a ladyback model.  It does not have a headtube badge though.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles . We recommend that new members [take the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get to know how to make best use of the site. This answer would be much better if you included some of the headtube pictures you found and perhaps even one of a similar tandem from that manufacturer.